# Sometime IOrganizationService object is null

Tags: c#, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, xrm

I've noticed usually after a request that has a lot of records if I try to make another Organization request the IOrganizationService object will be null for some time.

```
CrmServiceClient conn = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);

IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null ?
                    (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;    

OrganizationServiceContext ocontext = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);
```

Right at the point where I'm trying to new up an OrganizationServiceContext the debugger will complain the service is null.

Anyway to avoid this?

Comment: Does `conn` have a value?

Comment: What's CrmServiceClient? How is an IOrganizationService instantiated? I can not see source code where such task's are done.

Comment: The `CrmServiceClient` has an [IsReady](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.isready) property. Did you try that?

Comment: @user743414 [CrmServiceClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient?view=dynamics-xrmtooling-ce-9) and [IOrganizationService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice?view=dynamics-general-ce-9) are Framework classes

Answer (score 3):

The `CrmServiceClient` implements `IOrganizationService` itself. You shouldn't need to reach into the internals to get the "real" service. It's in theory better to use the outer service, because it handles token refresh automatically.

In my experience, when the inner service is `null`, it's because the connection failed somehow. Did you look at `conn.IsReady` and `conn.LastCrmError`?

Comment: thanks indeed you are right the isready would be false during these trip ups. I'm trying to figure out how to avoid that, because once it's false - of course it will blow up.

Comment: What does the error in `LastCrmError` say?

Shot in the dark: Are you specifying `RequireNewInstance=True` in your connection string? If you're not, could you give it a go?

Comment: Yes RequireNewInstance = True, and the LastCrmError is as follows: Unable to Login to Dynamics CRMOrganizationWebProxyClient is nullOrganizationWebProxyClient is nullOrganizationWebProxyClient is nullOrganizationWebProxyClient is nullOrganizationWebProxyClient is null

Comment: I know you mentioned using the outer service, now sure how. I use the OrganizationServiceContext since I'm doing a query that has Entity Reference and filters.

Comment: That error is unfortunately not very helpful. Try tracing on the client, and see if you spot anything weird. Do you know how to set up `System.Diagnostics.Tracing` in your app, so that the  Xrm assemblies spit out debug info?

Comment: It should be possible to say `new OrganizationServiceProxy(conn)`, since `conn` implements `IOrganizationService`. Of course, this won't help if the `CrmServiceClient` can't connect.

Comment: I posted a method I created as of now so that it keeps trying to make a connection that is good to go, however this doesn't feel like the right approach, sometimes it takes almost over 20 seconds. I'm not sure how to set up System.Diagnostics.Tracing to go deeper, but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I put so far to keep it from blowing up, however sometimes it takes long though for the connection to be recreated in a ready state.

```
    public static CrmServiceClient getCrmServiceClient(string connectionString)
    {
        CrmServiceClient conn;
        conn = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);

        while (conn.IsReady == false)
        {
            conn = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
            if(conn.IsReady == false)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }
        return conn;
    }
```

Comment: Ugly but functional. Maybe bail with an error after 10 tries or something? :)

Comment: @gnud def. ugly lol, and yes it should bail after a few tries - we are thinking however the connection is not stable because the Dynamics system is on a load balancer (2 servers). In development environment, this is never an issue.